# Como proceder com execução em lote para metodos python

Tags: python

Tenho seguinte código abaixo:

```
def exemplo01():
    return 'exemplo01'

def exemplo02():
    return 'exemplo02'

def exemplo03():
    return 'exemplo03'

def run():
    #list of <class 'function'>
    fx = []
    fx.append(exemplo01)
    fx.append(exemplo02)
    fx.append(exemplo03)

    for item in fx:
        print(item())
        print('-'*30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Este código funciona perfeitamente. Mas desejo alterar a implementação do run().

```
def run():
    l = []
    for i in range(1, 4):
        l.append('exemplo{:0>2}'.format(i))

    for i in l:
        print(i())
        print('-'*30)
```

Na primeira implementação o array é da class function, na segunda str, tentei realizar um Cast mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é porque `exemplo01` é uma função, enquanto `i` é uma string, apesar de ter o mesmo nome da função, o meu concelho é usar um dicionário para mapeares a `key` (chave, neste caso o mesmo nome da função) ao `value` (função):

```
...
l = {}
for func in [exemplo01, exemplo02, outrafunc]:
    l[func.__name__] = func
...
```

Depois é só chamar desta maneira:

```
l['exemplo01']() # ou neste caso, l[i]()
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/DullDecentInterfacestandard)

Outra maneira de fazer mais parecida com a da pergunta, é usar [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), MAS:

**ATENÇÃO:**

caso opere sobre inputs externos ou dados que não tenhas controlados **NÃO RECOMENDO**, é muito inseguro caso não saibas com certezas sobre o quê que vai atuar:

```
...
l = []
    for i in range(1, 4):
    l.append('exemplo{:0>2}'.format(i))

for i in l:
    print(eval(i)())
    print('-'*30)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/UnlawfulImpeccableJavadoc)

Neste caso, podes também usar [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), em vez do `eval` acima:

```
...
for i in l:
    print(globals()[i]())
    print('-'*30)
...
```

Nota que recomendo a primeira, com dicionário.